# How to send argument from desktop shortcut to a shell invoked UWP app that uses AUMID

Tags: command-line, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, shortcut-file

I have a win32 store app (desktop-bridge) converted and it works fine.

I want to create a desktop shortcut for this Store App that

- uses AUMID to start the app (solved below)
- and also passes an argument to it (**not solved**)

Here are the things I have tried:

I know how to start the app from command line using its AUMID.

```
explorer shell:appsfolder\[aumid]
```

I see that I can even use this as a target in a desktop shortcut and it works.

Now, I also want to pass arguments to the app which I can't do with the explorer command above.

But if I use start, it works:

```
start shell:appsfolder\[aumid] "an-argument"
```

But I can not put the above start command as target in a desktop shortcut. So how do I create a desktop shortcut that is able to start the store app above with an argument?

Another way to look at this question is, how to create a desktop shortcut with the start command?

**Update:** Got an answer from another question and the following works in the shortcut except that there is a blink when the command line window comes and goes.

```
cmd /c start shell:appsfolder\[aumid] "an-argument"
```

Comment: What is the complete syntax that combines `cmd /c start ...` and the `aumid`? Do you mean that `start shell:appsfolder\[aumid] "an-argument"` does not work, but `cmd /c start shell:appsfolder\[aumid] "an-argument"` does?

Comment: There might be a better way, but you can create a VBScript (or JScript) that runs the `cmd` hidden: https://superuser.com/q/62525/213663

Comment: I found a way. The shortcut option can be changed to Run Minimized. I can do this programmatically too when creating the shortcut.

Comment: But that does not hide the window, that only makes it less noticeable.

Comment: I know but it's enough for my purpose when there is no other solution.

Comment: There is a solution. See the link I've posted above.

Comment: The cmd solution is something that I could easily code in my store app for creating a shortcut and it works fine now. The script solution is much more difficult to implement for an App that runs on the user's machine in order to install it, run it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in the shortcut except that there is a blink when the command line window appears and then goes away after execution.

cmd /c start shell:appsfolder[aumid] "an-argument"

Comment: Coming back to the question after 2 years. This problem is no longer there in latest Windows 11. From wherever you start, the app starts in context. Not sure what Windows version I was using back then.